# Have a wire leftover- where does it go

Tags: dryer

Replacing stack W/D with 4 PRONG/WIRE- my new dryer has 3 wire terminals--where do I connect the fourth wire?

Comment: What make and model is your dryer? Can you post photos of its wiring diagram and of the cord-wiring compartment? I take it you're using a 4-wire cord?

Answer (score 2):

You must use 4-wire plugs and sockets.

3-wire was outlawed nearly 30 years ago, but you know how it is: somebody moved into a new house 25 years ago, they complained to the builder that their dryer is 3-prong so the builder changed the socket (illegally) to 3-prong to close the sale, because the building is the builder's bailiwick.  Then they buy a new dryer 20 years ago, and the installer sees a 3-prong outlets so changes the dryer plug to 3-prong because the appliance is the shop's bailiwick. 5 years later somebody else buys the house and tries to move in with their 4-prong dryer so they change the cord.  Round and round we go!  3-prong outlets are spreading like a cancer despite being outlawed.

So you need to get a 4-wire dryer cord - feel free to salvage it off the old dryer.

Then, on the dryer, there'll be a "bonding strap" that connects the chassis of the dryer to NEUTRAL (say what!? That's bootlegging!) That bonding strap must be removed.  Neutral and ground must be isolated, and hooked up to 2 different wires on the 4-prong cord.

Comment: So why are manufacturers selling 3 wire dryers? They must surely be illegal given what you describe. I can purchase 3 wire or 5 wire dryers depending on the size in my location, both legal.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm answering OP's question, which is about a stack washer-dryer that had 4-prong.  99% of the time when a dryer has 3-prong, it's NEMA 10.  All answers are by nature only in the context of questions, don't infer a blanket statement.

Comment: what happened to the earlier comment?

Comment: @SolarMike I thought it was overwrought...